# Sybase- sql query where date in last x days without considering time part

Tags: sql, sybase

I need to write a sybase query that will have a where clause with date within last x days like so -

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE 
date_col > [_last_x_days]
```

I was able to get datetime of last x days using

```
dateadd(day, -x, getdate())
```

However, the above method still gives me the time element based on when the query is run. How can I strip down the time part?
 i.e. convert **10-10-2011 15:00:45** to **10-10-2011 00:00:00**

Also, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!!!

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convert function will return the date without the time component.

dateadd( day, -x, CONVERT(DATE, getdate(), 103) )

See [this link](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm) for a complete description of CONVERT.

Comment: That link no longer gives anything relevant to Sybase.

Comment: Is that supposed to be my fault? What do you suggest I do about it?

Comment: Well, no need to take it personally ... However the link is now useless. Perhaps you can find the same info that was on that page and edit your answer to include it. In future, answers which are simply links are not great because of this type of problem - the page may disappear.

Comment: Point well taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
convert(datetime, substring(convert(varchar, dateadd(day, -x, getdate()), 20), 1, 11))
```

Comment: 20 was not a format, maybe the db I am querying is an older version. Thanks!